# Ajax call in a function in controller

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I am new to AngularJS.

I need to use a controller with a function called save, and make an ajax call inside the function.

My code looks like this now.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp1", []);

app.controller("AddController", ['$scope',$http {
    $scope.Save = function () {

    }
}])
```

I dont know how to proceed further.

Comment: use the $http (native from angular) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Umm.. Inside the function ?Will be glad if you help me with the code.

Comment: Keep in mind that ajax calls should be made in a service. And the service is then called by the function in your controller.

Answer (score 4):

Hers is the solution

```
 var app = angular.module("myApp1", []);

app.controller("AddController", ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){`
      $scope.Save = function () {
        $http({
            method : "POST",
            url : "url",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            data:data
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            console.log(response.data);
        }, function myError(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    }}]);
```

where data will be json data object that you have to save.

Comment: if you think my answer  is correct, please make it correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp1", []);

app.controller("AddController", ['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.Save = function () {
        $http.post(url, 
        {
            //data here
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            //success
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            //error
        });
    }
}]);
```